# how to call the function to determine the position of the container when changing orientation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to call the setCanvasPositions function, which recalculates the current position of the container when changing the orientation of the device. I don't want to rebuild the widget, I just need to call the function. How to do it?

```
class _CanvasState extends State<Canvas> {
     final GlobalKey canvasKey = GlobalKey();
     Offset? canvasPosition;

     @override
     void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance
           .addPostFrameCallback(setCanvasPositions);
     }
     void setCanvasPositions(_) {
        RenderBox? box = 
             canvasKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as 
                RenderBox?;
       setState(() {
            canvasPosition = 
            box?.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
        });
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
          key: canvasKey,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 30,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey, border: Border.all(color: 
                   Colors.blueGrey)),
         child: Stack(
            children: [
              StreamElementOnCanvas(canvasPosition, context)
         ],
     ),
   );
}
```

}

Comment: I think that because of `MediaQuery` your `build` method will be called in many cases, including on orientation changes. Can you try to put a debug print within the `build` method and see if it is written to console when you change orientation?

Comment: But if you call the method, it will rebuild the widget since you call setState from there

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I'm not well versed in Flutter yet :(